# Zabbix template

Tags: zabbix

Есть ли у кого шаблон для zabbix 3.2 для switche hp 2530-24g или динамический шаблон, чтобы все данные по каждому порту были в своей группе?
Пример:

```
Port 1+
    {Ошибки на входе
     Ошибки на выходе
     Скорость приёма
     Скорость отдачи}
```